# MyBatis : query java.util.Date with DATE type on MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql, date, ibatis, mybatis

In my Mapping XML I have :

```
<select id="getPatientsByBirthday"  parameterType="date" resultType="com.axiohelix.nozoki.entity.Patient">
            SELECT id AS id,
               pharumo_id AS pharumoId,
               code AS code,
               family_name AS familyName,
               first_name AS firstName,
               family_name_kana AS familyNameKana,
               first_name_kana AS firstNameKana,
               gender AS gender,               
               address AS address,
               tel AS tel
        FROM tbl_patient
        WHERE birthday = #{id}
    </select>
```

where birthday is a **DATE** type in MYSQL database.

My Mapper interface is like this :

```
public interface PatientMapper {

    void insertPatient(Patient patient);
    Patient getPatientById(Integer id);
    Integer getPatientCount();
    List<Patient> getPatientsByBirthday(Date  bday);
}
```

I tried to query patients with particular birthday as:

```
Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(1980, 8, 15);
Date bday=cal1.getTime();

List<Patient> plist=mapper.getPatientsByBirthday(bday);
```

Even though there are records with the given date,this return empty list.

Anytips ?

Comment: Share your Mapper interface implementation along with result mappings in XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your mapping xml likes this;

```
 <select id="getPatientsByBirthday"  parameterType="java.util.Date" resultType="com.axiohelix.nozoki.entity.Patient">
        SELECT id AS id,
           pharumo_id AS pharumoId,
           code AS code,
           family_name AS familyName,
           first_name AS firstName,
           family_name_kana AS familyNameKana,
           first_name_kana AS firstNameKana,
           gender AS gender,               
           address AS address,
           tel AS tel
        FROM tbl_patient
        WHERE birthday = #{date}
</select>
```